# websocket deployment fails due to "MessageHandler for type x already registered" when x is not registered

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, java-ee-7

My websocket's `@OnMessage` method is generating the following exception at deployment time:

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Class test.MyWebsocketEndpoint. MessageHandler for type: class test.MyInput already registered..
```

As far as I can tell, there is no such thing! This is the only onmessage event I have.

I have worked the problem down to the following SSCCE which was created as a new project and exhibits the problem I am having.

**Endpoint:**

```
package test;

import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/endpoint")
public class MySocketEndpoint
{
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session)
    {
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(MyInput input)
    {
    }
}
```

**MyInput:**

```
package test;

public class MyInput
{
}
```

**MyInputDecoder:**

```
package test;

import javax.websocket.DecodeException;
import javax.websocket.Decoder;
import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;

public class MyInputDecoder implements Decoder.Text<MyInput>
{
    @Override
    public MyInput decode(String s) throws DecodeException
    {
        return new MyInput();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willDecode(String s)
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(EndpointConfig config)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {
    }
}
```

Here are some bits of information that might be useful...

- If I change my onmessage method to an `onMessage(String)` instead, that does deploy just fine without any exceptions, and I can println the string to see the message sent to the server, but if I change it back to using `MyInput` again, then the error returns.
- If I comment out my onmessage method then redeploy, then the deployment
  works fine, though obviously without any onmessage logic.
- Despite the exception, the project does deploy other resources. After
  deployment, I can go to the web page that a project contains and
  see the static content. The failure only interrupts the websocket itself.
- The DeploymentException causes a ServletException with message "Web socket server initialization failed" farther up the stack, which in turn causes an InstantiationException farther up the stack.

I'm confused. Since that method is the only place that uses the annotation and the only one that uses MyInput class, how is there a handler already registered? How do I deploy with a successful onmessage event which uses a decoded object? Are there any pitfalls I'm running into, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The `@ServerEndpoint` annotation needs to know where the encoders and decoders are. See [ServerEndpoint javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html).

Example:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/endpoint", decoders={MyInputDecoder.class})
public class MySocketEndpoint
{
    ...
}
```

Otherwise it does not know where to find the decoder for the class that needs to be decoded.

I am not sure why this caused the error stating that `MyInput` was already registered, as that message is misleading, but it does fix it nonetheless.

Comment: After debugging for a couple of hours, it figures that I would realize what I had done less than a half hour after asking my initial question. Oh well - if I hadn't asked the question here I probably would not have taken the time to do a Q&A, so at least it's here now for future use.